# Doctrine cascade refresh on one to many association not working

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm using

```
$em->refresh($entity);
```

in my functional tests to refresh the entity and make assertions about it's contents after doing some changes to it.

The entity has oneToMany association with another entity and cascade action "refresh" is set on the relation.

```
// AppBundle/Entity/Item.php

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ItemPackage", mappedBy="item", cascade={"refresh"})
 */
private $packages;
```

Now, even if I call `$this->em->refresh($item);` in the tests, the packages collection is not refreshed and still holds outdated data (e.g. packages which were already removed and are not stored in the database anymore).

If I do the following and refresh each package in the collection by hand I'm able to get the actual data

```
// AppBundle/Tests/ItemControllerTest.php

$this->em->refresh($item);
$packages = $item->getPackages();
foreach($packages as $package) {
    $this->em->refresh($package);
}

$this->assertEquals(...);
```

According to this [What cascade "refresh" means in Doctrine 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34897830/what-cascade-refresh-means-in-doctrine-2) and the documentation [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations) should the refresh action work as I expect. Why do I have to refresh each member of the collection by hand? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you solve it? I'm stucked with that too, even after coding on my orm.yml file `cascade: ["refresh"]`. I'm accessing all the associations just like you to refresh each one individually

Comment: umm maybe there is a bug https://github.com/doctrine/orm/pull/6798