# How is it possible to completely refresh an Entity with a @OneToMany relationship?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

In my project there is a `Cart` and a `CartItem` entity, like this:

```
class Cart {

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="CartItem", mappedBy="cart")
     */
    private $items;

    // ...
}

class CartItem {

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Cart", inversedBy="items")
     * @JoinColumn(name="cart_id", referencedColumnName="cart_id")
     */
    private $cart;

    // ...
}
```

If I call `EntityManager::refresh($cart)`, then the items in it are not updated, only the `Cart` object.

How is it possible to refresh an object and all of its contents from the database, without explicitly call refresh on each of the sub elements?

I would like to avoid calling `EntityManager::clear()`, because it would cause bugs in other parts of the program.

Comment: Can you explain what are you really trying to accomplish and why?

Comment: I have multiple layers of relationships ( the `CartItem` has also an `ArrayList` in it). I update a lot of these elements/connections from the owning side, and I would like to update the `ArrayList` objects too if I call `EntityManager::refresh` on the root object

Comment: There's no "official" way of doing this. This would be madness, imagine an entity linked to a collection of 1 million entities, those linked to another millions of entities. You have do the refresh on your own based on your use case. Just hide this behind an interface and use this service across your app.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34897830/what-cascade-refresh-means-in-doctrine-2

Comment: you mean like flush?

Comment: @dixromos98 I mean like refresh

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
class Cart {

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="CartItem", mappedBy="cart", cascade={"refresh"})
     */
    private $items;

    // ...
}
```

Use "cascade" with caution as stated in the documentation:
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/best-practices.html#use-cascades-judiciously